# title of the song not appearing on startup

Tags: jquery

I've created a media Player for a website I'm working on and it's working really well except for a really annoying issue with the title of the music, and It's only happening when I host the website

first of, here's the code:

HTML:

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    listSongs();
})
</script>
</head>

[...]

<div id="DVRmediaPlayer">
    <div id="mediaPlayer">
        <div id="mediaName"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery ("media player.js"):

```
var url = "";
var songNames = [];
var Song = 1;

function songNameList() {
    $.get(nameLocation, function(data) {
        var lines = data.split("\n");
        $.each(lines, function(i, Name) {
            songNames[i] = Name;
        });
    }, 'text');
}

function listSongs() {
    $("#Musique").html("")
    url = "Musiques/" + Song + ".mp3";
    Musique.setAttribute("src", url)
    $("#mediaName").html(songNames[Song]);
}
```

[and here's a link to the website](http://googledrive.com/host/0ByBwY60ZsbQpZjFJaDhTQlRfdTg/)

the name of the song only appears when the song gets changed when it appears right away on local version

I don't really know why this would happen and if it can be fixed but I'm guessing it has something to do with the time it takes for the information to come by when it's hosted Vs. the time it take when the web page is opened locally

Comment: Wha is `Song` and where is it coming from? We're missing data here

Comment: What's `songNames`? In any case, the "A" in Ajax means "asynchronous", as you've probably guessed. You cannot depend on arbitrary return times. Whatever you do with `songNames` must happen only after `songNames` is actually populated, generally in a callback or promise. Also, beware the `url` in `listSongs`, it's global. This may be intentional, but it's not a great idea.

Comment: I've added some more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code on your website, it seems that songNames doesn't get populated until an ajax request in songNameList() is completed. If you call listSongs() inside the function called when the GET request completes, you can guarantee that songNames will be populated. So the function should look something like this

```
function songNameList() {
    $.get(nameLocation, function(data) {
        var lines = data.split("\n");
        $.each(lines, function(i, Name) {
            songNames[i] = Name;
        });
        listSongs(); //added line
    }, 'text');
}
```